# ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant UserfeedController::BLL):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails 4.2.4, Ruby 2.1.7

I have a module inside lib/ directory.

lib/BLL/user_feed.rb

```
module BLL
 class UserFeed

    def initialize
        logger.debug "Class has been initialized"
    end

    def get_user_feed(user_id)
      # logic here

        return {
         # object
        }
    end
 end
end
```

When I try to include that in my controller to use my user_Feed logic,

it's throwing

**ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant UserfeedController::BLL):**

error.

I am not sure what's wrong.

```
 class UserfeedController < ApplicationController
  include BLL

 before_action :authenticate_user!

  def show
   # some logic
  end
end
```

Comment: return a dictionary with what I get out from the database.

Comment: I think an extra end got in while composing this post. Edited it and made it correct, the return is not on the class level, it's on the method level

Comment: Are you aware that Rails doesn't include the `lib` folder into its load path? Did you include something like `config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')` into your `config/application.rb`?

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. Thank you for the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never version of Rails do not include the `lib` folder into the application's loadpath per default. To include the `lib` folder into the loadpath add the following to your `config/application.rb`:

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

Comment: when I try to deploy this to heroku, I get the same error again. Should I be adding this to any environment config files as well?